# How to write a program for reading the perimeter of a triangle by coordinates?

Tags: c++, arrays, math

> Create a TREUGOL structure, the fields of which will be three real
> arrays of 2 elements each, specifying the X and Y coordinates of the
> vertices of the triangle on the plane, and one real variable in which
> the perimeter of the triangle will be located. Create an instance of
> the structure via the structure name using the tag. In the program,
> fill in the coordinates with numbers entered from the keyboard,
> calculate the perimeter and enter the found value in the last field of
> the structure. Display the value of the last field on the screen.

This is my code:

```
$ vim test0.cc

$ cat test0.cc
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct TREUGOL

{

    float X,Y,arr,P;

};

int main()

{   

    TREUGOL coord;

    for(coord.arr=1;coord.arr<=3;coord.arr++)

    {

        cout<<"Print X and Y for coord"<<coord.arr<<":"<<endl;

        cin>>coord.X;

        cin>>coord.Y;

        cout<<coord.X<<"    "<<coord.Y<<endl;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

```
$ g++ -o test0 test0.cc

$ ./test0
```

```
Print X and Y for coord1:

3.1

3.3 

3.1 3.3

Print X and Y for coord2:

2

5

2   5

Print X and Y for coord3:

5

1

5   1
```

I have already written the coordinates using the structure, now how do I calculate the perimeter from these coordinates?

Comment: Just use Pythagoras theorem?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Why Pythagoras? you just need to find the perimeter of the triangle with the vertices. https://znanija.com/task/3346065

Comment: The link you give uses Pythagoras as well

Comment: @LearningMathematics Oh, maybe I misunderstood you. I apologize.

Comment: implement a `float distance(VertexType vertex1, VertexType verted2);` function (or preferrably go with `double` instead of floats to represent the floating point values. This allows you to just output the sum of the distances vertex1 to vertex2, vertex2  to vertex3 and vertex3 to vertex1. *"Create a TREUGOL structure, the fields of which will be three real arrays of 2 elements each"* You don't meet these requirements of the assignment. The struct should contain 3 members of the same type storing the info about one vertex each. (e.g. `struct TREUGOL { double[2] vertex1; ... };`)